# CardView not showing below text view

Tags: android, android-layout

So i have this piece of code but the card isnt showing below the text but it will show to the right of the text if i make the texts width `wrap_content`. I want the card to show below the text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Basic Calculators"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/basicLabel"
            android:textColor="#606060"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/paceCard"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
            cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:onClick="CardClick">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="8dp">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Pace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/paceLabel"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/roundchevron"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/paceLabel"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: As @ahmad pointed out, you always need orientation for a LL... I +1 your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of that you did not put any orientation for linearlayout

put orientation like below it will fix your problem

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
```

and when you use scrollview it is better to make height wrap_content

Comment: your welcome my friend if you get your answer please choose my answer till i get rep